# Php, how to pass a class reference to a method?

Tags: php

```
assertTriggerThisException ('Exception');
assertTriggerThisException ('AnotherExceptionClass');

function assertTriggerThisException ($exceptionClassname)
{
    try
    {
        something what triggers an exception
    }
    catch ($$exceptionClassname $e) // error
    {
    }
}
```

so I want to pass a reference to the class itself, but this causes syntax error. I want to say "dinamically" to expect an exception, is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try something like this

```
$someClass = 'SomeException';

try
{
    $some->thing();
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    switch (get_class($e))
    {
        case $someClass:
            echo 'Dynamic exception.';
            break;
        default:
            echo 'Normal exception.';
    }
}
```